# How to query this in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a model `submission` and it **has_many** `submissionstate` (and two tables `submissions` and `submissionstates` respectively).

`submissionstates` has a foreign key `submission_id` and another `state_id` column (and `updated_at`, `id`)

Every time if there is state change for `submission`, a new entry with the new state will be created in the `submissionstates` table.

I want to show entries that has `state_id` = **0** and the state is the **latest** state of the submission.

For example, a `submission` has two states (A(state_id = 0) and B (state_id = 1)), B is added after A. So I do **not** want this submission to be shown on the page since even though it has A, it is not the latest state (which is B).

I used:

```
@submissions = Submission.includes(:submissionstates).where("submissionstates.state_id = 0").all
```

But the result will includes all the state with `state_id` = 0 even if they are not the latest state of a submission.

What should I change in the query in order to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your Database structure!

You have to remember one thing ALWAYS when it comes to relational databases: **There's no general or automatic ordering of the rows!**

What I mean: You can't rely on the order of an query's output. The problem is: The DBMS optimizes your query, and if you don't call `ORDER BY` it is not defined in which order it will return the rows. (Even if it looks like it's always the same order, it could change on upgrading the DBMS or simply because a sack of rice fell over in China). **DON'T RELY ON THAT!**

So there's only one logical solution: A third column for your `submissionstate` table, either an auto-generated primary key or a timestamp. If you won't ever need the time of creation, go with the primary key.

Then your table would look like:

```
id | submission_id | state_id
-----------------------------
1  | 4             | 3
2  | 8             | 3
3  | 4             | 2
4  | 6             | 1
5  | 4             | 5
6  | 8             | 0
```

If I understood you correctly, you want those results:

- If you look for `submission_id = 4` you want to receive `state_id = 5`
- If you look for `submission_id = 8` you want to receive `state_id = 0`
- If you look for `submission_id = 6` you want to receive `state_id = 1`

Right?

---

### Solution(s):

So, when an `id` field is given, the query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT submission_id, state_id
FROM submissionstates ss
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(id) as id
  FROM submissionstates ss
  GROUP BY submission_id
) x
ON ss.id = x.id
```

If you only want the rows where the current state_id = 0, then:

```
SELECT submission_id, state_id
FROM submissionstates ss
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(id) as id
  FROM submissionstates ss
  GROUP BY submission_id
) x
ON ss.id = x.id
WHERE state_id = 0
```

If you already have a created_at column, then use it instead of the id column:

```
SELECT submission_id, state_id
FROM submissionstates ss
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at
  FROM submissionstates ss
  GROUP BY submission_id
) x
ON ss.created_at = x.created_at
WHERE state_id = 0
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. Yes sort order needs to be considered but there is nothing wrong with ordering by create_at or updated_at columns but it doesn't explain how to get the results that John is looking for and it doesn't address the issue of scale-ability. Over time this approach is going to grind to a halt

Comment: The op is looking for all states where current state is 0

Comment: of course there's nothing wrong with ordering by `created_at`, but he hasn't written anything about this field, so I'd say, there is no such column. I've written a query which solves his problem, when an auto incementing `id` is given.

Comment: Okay, if that's true, I'll expand my solution ;)

Comment: Of course there is a created_at column. Why on earth wouldn't there be? It would take some effort to remove that column so John would know that it is not there if he had done so

Comment: If he hadn't created the DB using rails generator, then there is no `created_at` or `id` column. And if he has used rails generator, he had only to remove a single line from the migrations file ;) ... but hey, I've posted 3 possible solutions ;)

Comment: sorry for the missing information, I actually have the `id` and the `created_at` columns

Comment: Thank you very much for those answers! In my case, I will use the third solution you provide, any idea how to write that in Ruby?

Comment: You have no model for SubmissionState, right? You could create one for it, then you could do `SubmissionState.find_by_sql("THE QUERY HERE")`.  (Don't forget the belongs_to and has_many etc.). ... Maybe there's another option, but for that you must tell, whether your query should result in a `Submission` object or a `State` object or if you need both.

Comment: @BenjaminM, yes I have a model for `SubmissionState`

Comment: Then simply try `@submissionstate = SubmissionState.find_by_sql("THE QUERY HERE")`. Should work out of the box. Then you can do things like `@submissionstate.state` or `@submissionstate.submission` to get the connected objects.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question but it solves your problem

You say

> For example, a submission has two states (A(state_id = 0) and B
>   (state_id = 1)), B

Which is just wrong. State implies singularity. i.e. a kettle can not be both boiling and cold.
Consider moving your state flag into the submissions table.
If you need to know when states changed then keep your submissionstates table but you would be using this for a totally different purpose.

by doing this you can then use

```
@submissions = Submission.where("state" = 0)
```

You could then set up scopes for each state if you wished e.g.

scope :state_0, where(:state => 0)
Which leaves you with

```
@submissions = Submission.state_0
```

Which is far more scale-able than your approach
By keeping the submissionstates table you can still list the dates and times of changes to states for a particular submission by making use of the `created_at` field but this becomes more of an auditing trail than for normal live usage

**UPDATE based on comments**

Using a separate submissionstates table is fine as it will give you the audit trail you need but you should still hold the current state on the submission table.

Updating the submission record every time a state changes is simple enough to achieve in a and performance wise it's no big deal especially when compared to the performance issue you WILL face if trying to determine the current state from the submissionstates table.

I'm saying that you need both. If there is an issue you have with keeping the current state on the submissions table then please shout and I'll see if I can address that

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I decide to use a separate `submissionstates ` table simply because I do not want to UPDATE the entry every time the states changes, instead I want to INSERT a new entry to keep track of each state change, it is more like a model versioning approach.

Comment: And yes you were right, a submission cannot have multiple states at the same time, that's why I always want the `latest` state :)